# Trying to prove Heisenberg's uncertainty wrong

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, wave-particle-duality

**Heisenberg’s uncertainty principle** states that we cannot determine the position and momentum of a particle at a time. I think I have an idea to prove it wrong ( although I believe I must be wrong here) :

Taking two electrons,, $e_1$ and $e_2$ in motion, we can determine the precise position of $e_1$ and the precise momentum of $e_2$.

Since we know that the momentum of both electrons is mathematically related to each other, we could conclude that the precise momentum that we measured of $e_2$ is the same as that of $e_1$.
Hence the position and momentum of $e_1$ is determined at the same time.

Comment: How do you know the relation between the electrons?

Comment: I don't know much about quantum mechanics but i have once seen somewhere Einstein try to disprove uncertainty principle but wasn't able to make it complete and concrete , the intuition was similar to yours try looking into it.also uncertainty has been seen experimental evidence it may be difficult to disprove theoretical but never impossible try it.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/528990/contradiction-with-the-uncertainty-principle-using-repeated-measurements.

Comment: Something similar

Answer (score 2):

You’re describing what’s known two particles in an entangled state, in which momentum measurements of the two are perfectly anticorrelated. Quantum mechanics teaches us that any measurement on one of the two particles breaks the entanglement. So, once you make a position measurement on the first electron the particles’ momentum are no longer anticorrelated. Therefore, a subsequent momentum measurement on the second particle doesn’t tell you anything about the first.

Comment: Oh thank you so much !